# understanding how the matchesSelector method works with call()

Tags: javascript

I was basically going through a few JS functions online and came across the following snippet of code:

```
(function(doc) {
   matches = 
      doc.matchesSelector ||
      doc.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      doc.mozMatchesSelector ||
      doc.oMatchesSelector ||
      doc.msMatchesSelector;
})(document.documentElement);

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if ( matches.call( e.target, 'ul a') ) {
      // proceed
   } 
}, false);
```

The above code is basically checking if the target element matches the `e.target` , now I do understand how `call()` works in Js , but somehow I am not able to understand how the following works:

```
matches.call( e.target, 'ul a')
```

I have seen `call()` being used a lot with functions, but the above is unusually ,

does the above code effectively translate to The following ::

```
e.target.matches('ul a')
```

?

It would be great if somebody could explain this part to me, as I have been struggling with this for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

*"does the above code effectively translate to The following: `e.target.matches('ul a')`?"*

Yes it does.

As you can read in the [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) docs, the first parameter passed to `call` is used as `this` argument in the method you've called `call` on.
Any remaining arguments are passed on to the method.